# sql server , set N prefix as unicode for all queries by default

Tags: sql-server, query, c#

Is there any option in ms sql server which use N prefix for my database.
There are many query in my application which non of them use N prefix for nvarchar fields , and now I have to set N for all of them and it takes long time to do.
My collatation is Persian_100 and it need unicode (N prefix) so any advise is appreciated

```
select * from table1 where field1=N'حمید' ;
```

I want skip N prefix in my query , but it acts as unicode for all type of queries:

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no way to do this.

Any option that did what you want would be extremely confusing because there would need to be a way to turn it *off* within the string literal syntax. There are other considerations (like storage size) to be aware of when choosing data types, so a setting like this could be very dangerous to put in play.

---

With regards to .NET applications that send parameterized T-SQL statements to SQL Server, the framework takes care of this for you because a .NET [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) inherently supports Unicode and things were built using that assumption. This applies to ORM-type libraries as well if they're programmed well.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
IDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = @name";

IDbDataParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
param.DbType = DbType.String;
param.ParameterName = "@name";
param.Value = "dbo";
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

What actually gets sent to SQL Server is this (line break added for clarity):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = @name',
    N'@name nvarchar(3)',@name=N'dbo'
```

You can see that the framework automatically used a Unicode type for the parameter (the length of 3 is a separate discussion entirely...).

The places where you need to modify code are in situations where SQL queries are not parameterized (or are unparameterizable, i.e., DDL) -- in other words, queries that have parameters concatenated directly into the string, or contain string constants. See my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19566/2718) for an example of how to avoid SQL injection issues when using dynamic SQL.

Comment: +1 but is worth calling out that the .Net way of supporting string has a dark side, namely forcing table scans when `WHERE varchar = @value` is used naively with `Parameters.AddWithValue`. See [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@yourparam", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
sqlcmd.Parameters["@yourparam"].Value = "حميد";
```

Comment: You may want to add some explanation to the code snippet you provided, particularly how it is different from the other answer.